CURL (PHP) works locally but it doesn't on remote server (curl_error #26)
I try to send photo via Telegram bot, so I wrote the code (a part of it):
$img_path = "https://www.example.com/path/to/file.jpg";
$method = "sendPhoto";
$arrayQuery = array(
    "chat_id" => CHAT_ID,
    "photo" => curl_file_create($img_path, $img_mime, $img_name),
    "caption" => $caption,
    "parse_mode" => "HTML",
    "show_caption_above_media" => True,
);
try {
    $ch = curl_init('https://api.telegram.org/bot'.BOT_TOKEN.'/'.$method);
    if ($ch === false) {
        throw new Exception('failed to initialize');
    }
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $arrayQuery);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    $res = curl_exec($ch);
    if ($res === false) {
        throw new Exception(curl_error($ch), curl_errno($ch));
    }
} catch(Exception $e) {
    trigger_error(sprintf(
    'Curl failed with error #%d: %s', $e->getCode(), $e->getMessage()),
    E_USER_ERROR);
} finally {
    if (is_resource($ch)) {
        curl_close($ch);
    }
}

So this code works fine locally, but when I upload it to remote server curl throws error 26.
Can anybody help me with this?
I tried to add CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST false, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER false but not result

Error 26 is "couldn't open file". This may be a permissions thing on the server, since you said it works locally.

@aynber
$img_path = https://www.example.com/path/to/file.jpg
Everybody has access to the file

That's the web URL. The permissions is talking about the file permissions on the server, which is usually /path/to/file. The webserver user may not have permissions to write the file.

Topically Related: Telegram BOT Api: how to send a photo using PHP? and Sending Image via Telegram-Bot API with PHP and Send Photo uploaded in folder to Telegram BOT and upload photo and text from form input and sending to telegram bot with php and Sending photo from URL with Telegram Bot - php

The Telegraph documentation for sendPhoto says

Instead of supplying a local path and filename, you may just pass the image URL

So all you need is:
$arrayQuery = array(
    "chat_id" => CHAT_ID,
    "photo" => $img_path,
    "caption" => $caption,
    "parse_mode" => "HTML",
    "show_caption_above_media" => True,
);

The problem you are experiencing, where curl_file_create works with a URL from your local but not the remote server, may be due to security restrictions of the allow_url_fopen setting.
From php's documentation:

This option enables the URL-aware fopen wrappers that enable accessing URL object like files.

Although this option is enabled by default, many hosting platforms will disable it as it is considered a security risk.

Telegram Documentation says that type can be InputFile or String (Photo to send. Pass a file_id as String to send a photo that exists on the Telegram servers (recommended), pass an HTTP URL as a String for Telegram to get a photo from the Internet, or upload a new photo using multipart/form-data). Moreover, my code works locally.

I have edited my answer to more directly address the fact your code works locally but not on the remote host. The issue is most likely with the remote host setting the php allow_url_fopen setting to false. Given the security concerns the approach suggested of passing the url directly may be preferable to enabling this setting.

Thank you very much for detailed explanation. Your code works for me.
